# Firefox transition not working (with declared initial values)

Tags: css, firefox, transition, css-animations

The following transition animation works on all browsers except Firefox. I know you have to initialise the attributes to be transitioned in Firefox. In this case the three attributes that are animated, border, letter-spacing and background, are given explicitly declared default values.

```
>a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: border .5s, letter-spacing .2s, background .5s;
    -moz-transition: border .5s, letter-spacing .2s, background .5s;
    -ms-transition: border .5s, letter-spacing .2s, background .5s;
    -o-transition: border .5s, letter-spacing .2s, background .5s;
    transition: border .5s, letter-spacing .2s, background .5s;
    background: transparent;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
>a:hover {
    background: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

[There's a working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexkaskasoli/83wz7z1r/4/)

The submenu elements are the elements who's transition anim works on all except Firefox (v.31 OS X).

(I apologise for the long and cryptic CSS  in the fiddle, I use SASS. I've commented the relevant part of the CSS with:

```
/*
   TWISTED TRANSITION
*/
```

to help you find it)

EDIT:

Seeing Fabio's comment I'm wondering if other people could leave me a comment if it works for them or not. I'm starting to wonder if it's not an OS X FireFox glitch.

Comment: works perfect for me in FF, not sure what do you mean

Comment: @Fabio The hover effect works for me in FF but it is not animated. It's an instant change as if there were no `transition:` parameters set. In Chrome for example, I get the nice and smooth transition effect. May be my version and my OS, FF 31 OS X. Cleared the cache and even rebooted my laptop in the mean time, the problem is definitely still here. I'm also confused as to why the parent menu's transition animation work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style the li, instead of the a

```
header nav > .ul_wrap > ul > li > ul > li {
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0;
display: block;
color: white;
width: 100%;

transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
background: transparent;
letter-spacing: 1px;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
header nav > .ul_wrap > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
background: #3b4979;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
letter-spacing: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #273565 0 0 2px 1px inset;
-moz-box-shadow: #273565 0 0 2px 1px inset;
box-shadow: #273565 0 0 2px 1px inset;
}
header nav > .ul_wrap > ul > li > ul > li > a{color:#fff}
```

I tried it in FF and works perfectly fine. [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fs68xL8n/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Still confused as to why the `a` won't animate in this case but at least it's working!